# Magento2: how to display 4 digit prices and tier prices in the admin > catalog?

Tags: magento2, price, tierprice, format

How to modify Magento 2 in order to be able to show 4 digit prices and tier prices in the admin catalog? I can save 4 digit prices and they go in the database, even when I load a product edit form in the admin I can see a JSON on the source of the page which contains my 4 digit prices, but in the form itself the prices are all rounded to 2 digits. How can I get the form to show my 4 digit prices without rounding them down to 2 digits?

Answer (score 0):

Hey after hours of searching I finally found how! its in vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/Currency.php line 74!

change this bit:

```
protected $_options = array(
    'position'  => self::STANDARD,
    'script'    => null,
    'format'    => null,
    'display'   => self::NO_SYMBOL,
    'precision' => 2,
    'name'      => null,
    'currency'  => null,
    'symbol'    => null,
    'locale'    => null,
    'value'     => 0,
    'service'   => null,
    'tag'       => 'Zend_Locale'
);
```

change `'precision' => 2,` for `'precision' => 4,`

Now I just need to figure the right way to apply this change from a clean module.